# $E[\frac{X_i}{X_1+...+X_n}]=E[\frac{X_j}{X_1+...+X_n}]$ for i.d. $X_k$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be positive-integer-valued random variables with the same distribution. Then:

$$E\left[\frac{X_i}{X_1+...+X_n}\right]=E\left[\frac{X_j}{X_1+...+X_n}\right]$$ $\forall 1\le i,j\le n, i\ne j$.

I know that it must be true but I don't see why this is implied by $E[X_i]=E[X_j]$. Can anyone prove it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The result is basically saying chose any random variable then the expectation of that over the sun will be $E$. So it doesn't matter which random variable you choose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{X_i}{X_1+...+X_n}\stackrel{d}{=}\frac{X_j}{X_1+...+X_n}
$$
since the $X_k$ are identically distributed. The result follows.

Comment: This doesn't simply follow from the identical distribution. For a counterexample, let $N$ be standard normal and set $X_i := (-1)^{i+1} N$. Take $n=3$ and $i=1$,$j=2$, then the left-hand side is equal to $1$ and the right-hand side is equal to $-1$.